# Translation Golf XIII - In a hole in the ground

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

Vamos a dedicar la edición de la buena suerte del *translation-golf* a la introducción de *The Hobbit*.

> In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit. Not a nasty, dirty, wet hole, filled with the ends of worms and an oozy smell, nor yet a dry, bare, sandy hole with nothing in it to sit down on or to eat: it was a hobbit-hole, and that means comfort.
>
> <sub>(185 caracteres)</sub>

Es un texto más corto que en otras ediciones, pero espero que dé juego. La traducción oficial dice tal que así (200 caracteres exactos):

> En un agujero en el suelo, vivía un hobbit. No un agujero húmedo, sucio, repugnante, con restos de gusanos y olor a fango, ni tampoco un agujero seco, desnudo y arenoso, sin nada en que sentarse o que comer: era un agujero-hobbit, y eso significa comodidad.

¡Esto es [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf), la traducción con menor número de caracteres que respete el original gana!

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: Carlos, esta partida ya lleva abierta 11 días. Podrías por favor declarar un ganador para que esta persona pueda empezar el juego siguiente? Gracias.

Comment: @Diego os ruego me disculpéis. La semana pasada empecé mis vacaciones y se me ha ido el santo al cielo.

Comment: Oh no! Siento haberte molestado estando de vacaciones :-(
Disfrútalas, que seguramente serán bien merecidas.

Comment: @Diego no, no, si me he traído el portátil para poder seguir participando en el sitio (y en PPCG, que estoy enganchado), y también tengo la app de Stack Exchange, para responder desde cualquier parte. Solo quise decir que como tenía la cabeza pensando más en que me iba de vacaciones que en cualquier otra cosa, se me pasó cerrar la pregunta... :-)

Comment: @walen pues yo la verdad es que no, me gusta que me sorprendan a cada pregunta con textos nuevos y así voy descubriendo cosas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 129 caracteres

> En un hoyo vivía un hobbit. No en uno feo, sucio, húmedo, con gusanos asomando y olor a lodo; ni uno arenoso, seco, nudo sin asiento ni comida. Era un "hoyo hobbit": cómodo.

- [**hoyo**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=hoyo) *per se* ya implica "en la tierra".
- Duplicando la partícula "**en**" se deja claro que estamos hablando del hoyo.
- "Con gusanos asomando": no se les ve todo el cuerpo, sólo un trozo.
- [**nudo**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=QhbG142) por **desnudo**, como traducción de *bare*.
- Uso de los dos puntos para enlazar "hoyo hobbit" y su significado de cómodo.

Comment: No se me había ocurrido que "filled with the ends of worms" pudiera significar "con gusanos asomando". Desde luego, así solo se les ve un trozo, como dices. Muy buena, ¡eres un duro competidor en esto del translation-golf! :-)

Comment: ¡Eres el ganador de esta edición!

Answer (score 3):

### <strike>150</strike> 149 Caracteres

> Vivía un hobbit en un hoyo del suelo que no era feo, sucio, húmedo, infecto de gusanos y apestoso, ni tampoco seco, vacío y arenoso sin nada para sentarse o comer, pues sus hoyos son cómodos.

---

[Feo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HlTPxWF):  adj. Que causa desagrado o aversión; De aspecto malo o desfavorable

[Infecto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LVIaJBX): adj. Infectado, contagiado, pestilente, corrompido.

<strike>[Grato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JVJdDz8) : adj. Gustoso, agradable.</strike>

Comment: Buena respuesta, lo único que no consigo ver es cómo "grato" puede ser sinónimo de "confort" o "confortable". ¿Podrías explicar un poco más esa relación?

Comment: Hay tanta diferencia entre "Confort: Bienestar o comodidad material" y "gustoso o agradable"? Si es así uso "confort" (y paso de 5 letras a 7. Total solo dos de diferencia y no discutimos :-) )

Comment: Si no es por discutir, era por elaborar un poco más la respuesta, dado que casi lo veo pero no del todo, necesito un empujoncito. :-)

Comment: Sorry, ese "discutir" era más un "analizar/argumentar" que un "polemizar/disputar". No quería que ninguno de los dos invirtiésemos demasiado tiempo o esfuerzo debatiendo si sí o si no, total por una letra. Además al cambiarlo se me ha ocurrido una mejora! A ver si alguien más se anima y participa.

Answer (score 3):

## 146 caracteres

Pobre Tolkien. En fin.

> En un hoyo en tierra vivía un hobbit. No era feo, sucio, mojado, con colas de bicho ni olor a limo; tampoco seco, vacío ni arenoso, sin dónde sentarse o comer: era un hoyo-hobbit, o sea cómodo.

Intenté ser fiel al orden y a los límites de las oraciones, con sólo alguna concesión:

- *nor yet* tiene tres matices: una negación y una doble conjunción, que separo en *tampoco... ni*.
- No convierto el *dónde* en *do* porque lo considero forzado (si alguien lo quiere editar, serían 143 caracetres).
- Traduzco *filled* por *con* porque evidentemente no quiere decir que esté lleno *sensu stricto*.
- No considero necesario explicitar el sujeto al principio de "no era...", porque la posible ambigüedad entre *hoyo* y *hobbit* queda resuelta al final de la misma oración.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]! Genial primera contribución. Mi única pega sería que "hoyo en tierra" queda un poco raro. No sería necesario un "la" antes de tierra? Cuando decimos que "No era feo, sucio, [...]" a quién nos referimos (el hobbit o el hoyo)? Desambigua un poco con la frase tras los ";". Aquí estoy siendo un poco tiquismiquis

Comment: @Diego tuve la misma duda, pero luego de darle vueltas, me parece que [tierra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zj5UJym) se usa también sin artículo: se prefiere más frecuentemente para significar cosas más específicas como *tierra firme*, pero tampoco se puede decir que esté mal: [ejemplos](http://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/hoyo+en+tierra.html), [otro ejemplo](https://books.google.cl/books?id=6rl_AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA163&ots=tFtk_B8t9f&dq=%22hoyo%20en%20tierra%22&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q=%22hoyo%20en%20tierra%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

### 175 caracteres

> En un hoyo del suelo vivía un hobbit. El hoyo no era feo, sucio ni húmedo, ni lleno de cabos de lombriz, ni exudaba olor; tampoco era seco, yermo o arenoso, sin donde sentarse o comer: era un pozo de hobbit, y estos eran cómodos.